# Visual C++ How to override event handler of parant class?

Tags: c++, mfc, overriding, eventhandler, ribbon-control

I need to override event wm_lbuttonup of CMFCRibbonSlider class

```
    class CMyRibbonSlider : public CMFCRibbonSlider
    {
     public:
       virtual void OnLButtonUp(CPoint point); // need this event handler!
    };

    void CMyRibbonSlider::OnLButtonUp(CPoint point)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Works!"))
        return;
    }
```

Use CMyRibbonSlider object in MainFrame class

```
    class CMainFrame : public CMDIFrameWndEx
    {
    ....
    CMyRibbonSlider*  SliderLine;
    }
```

When CMFCRibbonSlider control apears and I click left mousebutton, nothing happens. What do I do wrong?

**EDIT:**

initialization

```
CArray<CMFCRibbonBaseElement*, CMFCRibbonBaseElement*> ar;
m_wndRibbonBar.GetElementsByID(ID_SLIDER2, RibbonElementsArray);

m_wndRibbonBar.GetElementsByID(ID_START_BTN, ar);
RibbonElementsArray.Append(ar);

m_wndRibbonBar.GetElementsByID(ID_STOP_BTN, ar);
RibbonElementsArray.Append(ar);

m_wndRibbonBar.GetElementsByID(ID_SLIDER_LINE, ar); //HERE!
RibbonElementsArray.Append(ar);

m_wndRibbonBar.GetElementsByID(IDC_STATIC_TT, ar);
RibbonElementsArray.Append(ar);

Slider = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonSlider, RibbonElementsArray[0]);
btnStart = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonButton, RibbonElementsArray[1]);
btnStop = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonButton, RibbonElementsArray[2]);
SliderLine = (CMyRibbonSlider*)DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonSlider, RibbonElementsArray[3]); //and HERE!
TmpLable = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCRibbonLabel, RibbonElementsArray[4]);
```

also I have these event handlers in Mainframe class and they work:

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_SLIDER_LINE, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateSliderLine)
ON_COMMAND(ID_SLIDER_LINE, &CMainFrame::OnSliderLine)
```

SliderLine->GetPos() also returns right slider position, so I think initialization is right...

Comment: `CMyRibbonSlider*  SliderLine;` - that's all? Only pointer?

Comment: The code needs a bit more context. Since you say that the `CMyRibbonSlider` control appears, you cannot just have a pointer to it. It also needs to be constructed at some point. That code is important, as is your [message map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1.aspx).

Comment: Ofcourse it's not only a pointer. I added some code.

Answer (score 1):

It is seem like the ***CMFCRibbonSlider*** control isn't added correctly to ***CMFCRibbonPanel*** and therefore ***CMainFrame*** class does not expose slider’s messages through message map.
Try to use a method described in the following article: 
[Walkthrough: Creating a New Ribbon Application By Using MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309024(v=vs.90).aspx)

The code will be look like below.

**MyRibbonSlider.h**

```
#include "afxribbonslider.h"
#pragma once

class CMyRibbonSlider : public CMFCRibbonSlider
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyRibbonSlider)
public:
    CMyRibbonSlider();
    CMyRibbonSlider(UINT nID, int nWidth = 100);

// Implementation
public:
    virtual ~CMyRibbonSlider();
    virtual void OnLButtonUp(CPoint point); 
};
```

**MyRibbonSlider.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyRibbonSlider.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMyRibbonSlider, CMFCRibbonSlider)

CMyRibbonSlider::CMyRibbonSlider()
{
}

CMyRibbonSlider::CMyRibbonSlider(UINT nID, int nWidth)
    : CMFCRibbonSlider(nID, nWidth)
{   
}

CMyRibbonSlider::~CMyRibbonSlider()
{
}

void CMyRibbonSlider::OnLButtonUp(CPoint point)
{
    TRACE("\nCMyRibbonSlider::OnLButtonUp()");
    return;
}
```

Related declarations in the **CMainFrame.h**

```
afx_msg void OnSliderLine();
afx_msg void OnUpdateSliderLine(CCmdUI* pCmdUI);
```

**CMainFrame.cpp**

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CMDIFrameWndEx)
    ...
    ON_COMMAND(ID_SLIDER, &CMainFrame::OnSliderLine)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_SLIDER, &CMainFrame::OnUpdateSliderLine)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMainFrame::InitializeRibbon()
{
    ...
    bNameValid = strTemp.LoadString(*your title*);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    CMFCRibbonPanel* pPanelAdvanced = pCategoryHome->AddPanel(strTemp, m_PanelImages.ExtractIcon (*your icon*));    
    strTemp = _T("Slider"); 
    CMyRibbonSlider* pRibbonSlider = new CMyRibbonSlider(ID_SLIDER);
    pPanelAdvanced->Add(pRibbonSlider);
    ...
}

void CMainFrame::OnSliderLine()
{
    // TODO
}

void CMainFrame::OnUpdateSliderLine(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    // TODO
}
```